# Ruby on Rails - Windows 7 - installation problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7

I am installing ruby on rails.

I installed version 3.0.0 and then wanted to update it to version 3.0.1

So I removed the executable files by giving

```
gem uninstall rails
```

Then I again tried installing by giving

```
gem install rails -v 3.0.1
```

It says

```
Succesfully installed rails-3.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentaion details for rails -3.0.1
File not found: lib
```

I tested by giving

```
rails -v
```

Now it is saying an error called

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources list
ed in your Gemfile.
Try running `bundle install`.
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Do you get that error message by running 'rails -v'?

Comment: yes heikki. As soon as i hit return i got the message

Answer (score 2):

you're missing reading the instructions:

> Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources list
>   ed in your Gemfile.

That indicates that sqlite3-ruby is in your Gemfile, but is not installed, then:

> Try running `bundle install`

Did you ran `bundle install` to install the missing gems?

I would recommend you read Rails guides, specially the [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide.

Hope that helps